# Can't disconnect a Mac from a network

Tags: finder, network

I'm at a university campus and I connected to a Mac from network section on Finder. But apparently I can't delete it from Locations section. There is no eject button and I can't drag it.

I don't want to turn off the Locations section. I want to fully disconnect that Mac. When I turn off and on again the network it comes again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

In Finder you press CMD+K, then at the botton left, down arrow, then "clear recent servers".

Comment: Happy for you ;-)